# Загрузка видео по требованию

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, видео

Мне необходимо начинать загрузку видео с сервера  на странице после того как пользователь доскролит до этого места.
Видео на страницу вставляются **форычем** . Через тег **video**

```
<?if($arSection["UF_VIDEOSLIDER"]):?>
        <section class="main-slider-video">
            <?foreach ($arSection["UF_VIDEOSLIDER"] as $videoItem):?>
            <div class="item video">
                <video class="slide-video slide-media"
                       preload="metadata"
                       playsinline
                       autoplay
                       muted
                       loop>

                    <source src="<?=$videoItem["path"]?>" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>

                <h2 class="production-video__title"><?=$videoItem["title"]?></h2>
                <p class="production-video__note"><?=$videoItem["desc"]?></p>
            </div>
            <?endforeach;?>
        </section>
<?endif;?>
```

Не могу представить как начинать загрузку видео с сервера после скрола до определнного места. Есть идеи ? Предложения ?

Comment: js-ом определяем положение элемента видео на странице. Потом вешает хндлер на скролл страницы :  когда скролл будет попадать под положение элемента видео - запускать видео `vidEl.play()`

Comment: как минимум нужно убрать autoplay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Вот так:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");  

var body = $("html, body");
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var top_video = $("#myVideo").offset(); 
  
  if(scroll >= top_video.top){
        vid.play();
  }
})
```

```css
#myVideo {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
 
.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

p{
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body> 
 <p>Листать вниз!</p>
 <div style="margin-top:2500px"></div>
 <video muted loop id="myVideo"> 
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
 
</body> 
</html>
```

### Update 0.0.1 (PHP and Ajax)

*Всегда открыты для предложений рефакторинга кода :)*

**Файл *video.php*:**

```
<?php  

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$id = ( isset($_POST["id"]) ) ? $_POST["id"] : $id = 1;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE id = ".$id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["link"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close(); ?>
```

**Файл *index.html*:**

```js
var scrolling = false; 
var body = $("html, body");  
  
var myVideo1 = $("#myVideo1").offset().top;
var myVideo2 = $("#myVideo2").offset().top;
var myVideo3 = $("#myVideo3").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 
  
 if(scroll >= myVideo1){
  var div_video = $("#myVideo1");
 }
 if(scroll >= myVideo2){
  var div_video = $("#myVideo2");
 }
 if(scroll >= myVideo3){
  var div_video = $("#myVideo3");  
 }
 
 if (typeof div_video !== "undefined") { 
  if (scroll >= $(div_video[0]).offset().top) {
   if (!scrolling){
    $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "video.php",
     dataType: "text", 
     data: {id : $(div_video[0]).data("id")},
     success: function (response) {  
      $(div_video[0]).html('<source src="'+response+'"  type="video/mp4" >'); 
      
      div_video[0].play(); 
     }
    })    
   } 
   scrolling = true;  

    if( scroll  >=  $(div_video[0]).offset().top + $(div_video[0]).innerHeight()-100) {
    scrolling = false;  
   } 
  } 
 }   
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}
body{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}
.myVideo {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}  
.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
} 
p{
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body> 
 <p>Листать вниз!</p>
 <div style="margin-top:2500px"></div> 

 <video loop class="myVideo" data-id="1" id="myVideo1">  
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>

 <video loop class="myVideo"  data-id="2" id="myVideo2">  
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>

 <video loop class="myVideo" data-id="3" id="myVideo3">  
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>  

</body> 
</html>
```

**Структура базы данных:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чуть чуть не то .  Допустим  у меня на странице 3 видео . Когда я обновляю страницу эти видео сразу же загружаются  с сервера сжирая трафик. А мне надо чтоб когда я дошел до видео оно только только началось грузится с сервера

Comment: @Goryyn Вон оно как, понял.

Comment: Обновил ответ, при прокрутки до определенного блока подружатся видео с БД с таким же id как в атрибуте data-id, через ajax